# Having issues with setting up yii2 basic framework and ibm bluemix

Tags: yii2, ibm-cloud

Having issues with setting up yii2 basic framework and ibm bluemix.

I was using this link as a guide: https://github.com/Twanawebtech/yii2App-Bluemix/blob/master/README.md

### Step 1a: clone the code and setup

```
Open your terminal
$ git clone https://github.com/Twanawebtech/yii2App-Bluemix.git
$ cd yii2App-Bluemix
```

### Step 1b: Set cookie validation key in config/web.php file to some random secret string:

```
'request' => [
// !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty)
- this is    required by cookie validation
'cookieValidationKey' => '<secret random string goes here>',
],
```

### Step 1c: You can then access the application through the following URL:

```
http://localhost/yii2App-Bluemix/web
```

you should see the Congratulations Screen

[image: Congratulations Screen]

### Step 1d: Manifest

Go back to the yii2App-Bluemix folder 
and open the manifest file
rename name and host to the name you want to call it.

[image: Manifest File]

Go to the command prompt and using cloud Foundary CLI (once you have setup cloud Foundary CLI)

```
 enter cf login
 API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
 enter Email Address: 
 enter Password:
 Select a space (if you have more than one space allocated)
```

### Step 2: Push your code to Bluemix

```
   $ cf push yii2App-Bluemix -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git -s cflinuxfs2
```

[image: Completion of the Push to Bluemix]

### Step 3: Access your app by entering the following URL into your browser:

```
  http://yii2basic.mybluemix.net/yii
```

However I don't get the congratulations screen but instead I get the following which is the source code of the index.php file found in the web folder

[image: index.php source code]

What am I missing or forgot to do???

Comment: I don't know much about the Bluemix but `yii` is just a console script and shouldn't be accessible from the web. Maybe you need to ask Twanawebtech to fix this in readme. You need to point server to the proper entry script which is `web/index.php` - http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html says it can be done by setting `WEBDIR` in `options.json`.

Comment: By the way, there is nothing called **Yii2 basic Framework**, but there is **Yii2 Framework's basic application**. Checkout this [tag:yii2-basic-app] tag

Comment: @Bizley I tried creating a .bgconfig folder and put options.json with the following code inside: {
  "WEB_SERVER": "httpd",
  "LIBDIR": ".",
  "WEBDIR": "web",
  "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [
    "bz2",
    "zlib",
    "openssl",
    "curl",
    "mcrypt",
    "mbstring",
    "pdo",
    "zip",
    "fileinfo",
    "gd",
    "imagick",
    "intl",
    "mailparse",
    "memcache",
    "memcached",
    "mysqli",
    "opcache",
    "pdo_mysql",
    "pdo_pgsql",
    "pdo_sqlite",
    "pgsql",
    "Yii2"
  ]
}  and it crashed the bluemix cf push.

Comment: Consider opening issue at https://github.com/Twanawebtech/yii2App-Bluemix/issues